# I made module for vtiger 6.5 but it is not showing.

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

language and module file path

vtiger/language/en_us/Expenses.php

vtiger/modules/Expenses/Expenses.php

both file are same.

```
include_once 'modules/Vtiger/CRMEntity.php';
class Expenses extends Vtiger_CRMEntity {
    var $table_name = 'vtiger_expenses';
    var $table_index= 'expensesid';

    var $customFieldTable = Array('vtiger_expensescf', 'expensesid');

    var $tab_name = Array('vtiger_crmentity', 'vtiger_expenses', 'vtiger_expensescf');

    var $tab_name_index = Array(
            'vtiger_crmentity' => 'crmid',
            'vtiger_expenses' => 'expensesid',
            'vtiger_expensescf'=>'expensesid');

    var $list_fields = Array (
            /* Format: Field Label => Array(tablename, columnname) */
            // tablename should not have prefix 'vtiger_'
            'Summary' => Array('expenses', 'summary'),
            'Assigned To' => Array('crmentity','smownerid')
    );
    var $list_fields_name = Array (
            /* Format: Field Label => fieldname */
            'Summary' => 'summary',
            'Assigned To' => 'assigned_user_id',
    );

    // Make the field link to detail view
    var $list_link_field = 'summary';

    // For Popup listview and UI type support
    var $search_fields = Array(
            /* Format: Field Label => Array(tablename, columnname) */
            // tablename should not have prefix 'vtiger_'
            'Summary' => Array('expenses', 'summary'),
            'Assigned To' => Array('vtiger_crmentity','assigned_user_id'),
    );
    var $search_fields_name = Array (
            /* Format: Field Label => fieldname */
            'Summary' => 'summary',
            'Assigned To' => 'assigned_user_id',
    );

    // For Popup window record selection
    var $popup_fields = Array ('summary');

    // For Alphabetical search
    var $def_basicsearch_col = 'summary';

    // Column value to use on detail view record text display
    var $def_detailview_recname = 'summary';

    // Used when enabling/disabling the mandatory fields for the module.
    // Refers to vtiger_field.fieldname values.
    var $mandatory_fields = Array('summary','assigned_user_id');

    var $default_order_by = 'summary';
    var $default_sort_order='ASC';
```

}

root file

vtiger/Expenses.php

```
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';

$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;

$MODULENAME = 'Expenses';

$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($MODULENAME);
if ($moduleInstance || file_exists('modules/'.$MODULENAME)) {
    echo "Module already present - choose a different name.";
} else {
    $moduleInstance = new Vtiger_Module();
    $moduleInstance->name = $MODULENAME;
    $moduleInstance->parent= 'Tools';
    $moduleInstance->save();

    // Schema Setup
    $moduleInstance->initTables();

    // Field Setup
    $block = new Vtiger_Block();
    $block->label = 'LBL_'. strtoupper($moduleInstance->name) . '_INFORMATION';
    $moduleInstance->addBlock($block);

    $blockcf = new Vtiger_Block();
    $blockcf->label = 'LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION';
    $moduleInstance->addBlock($blockcf);

    $field1  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field1->name = 'summary';
    $field1->label= 'Summary';
    $field1->uitype= 2;
    $field1->column = $field1->name;
    $field1->columntype = 'VARCHAR(255)';
    $field1->typeofdata = 'V~M';
    $block->addField($field1);

    $moduleInstance->setEntityIdentifier($field1);

    $field2  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field2->name = 'expenseon';
    $field2->label= 'Expense On';
    $field2->uitype= 5;
    $field2->column = $field2->name;
    $field2->columntype = 'Date';
    $field2->typeofdata = 'D~O';
    $block->addField($field2);

    $field3  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field3->name = 'expenseamount';
    $field3->label= 'Amount';
    $field3->uitype= 71;
    $field3->column = $field3->name;
    $field3->columntype = 'VARCHAR(255)';
    $field3->typeofdata = 'V~M';
    $block->addField($field3);

    $field3  = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field3->name = 'description';
    $field3->label= 'Description';
    $field3->uitype= 19;
    $field3->column = 'description';
    $field3->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $blockcf->addField($field3);

    // Recommended common fields every Entity module should have (linked to core table)
    $mfield1 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $mfield1->name = 'assigned_user_id';
    $mfield1->label = 'Assigned To';
    $mfield1->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $mfield1->column = 'smownerid';
    $mfield1->uitype = 53;
    $mfield1->typeofdata = 'V~M';
    $block->addField($mfield1);

    $mfield2 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $mfield2->name = 'CreatedTime';
    $mfield2->label= 'Created Time';
    $mfield2->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $mfield2->column = 'createdtime';
    $mfield2->uitype = 70;
    $mfield2->typeofdata = 'T~O';
    $mfield2->displaytype= 2;
    $block->addField($mfield2);

    $mfield3 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $mfield3->name = 'ModifiedTime';
    $mfield3->label= 'Modified Time';
    $mfield3->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $mfield3->column = 'modifiedtime';
    $mfield3->uitype = 70;
    $mfield3->typeofdata = 'T~O';
    $mfield3->displaytype= 2;
    $block->addField($mfield3);

    // Filter Setup
    $filter1 = new Vtiger_Filter();
    $filter1->name = 'All';
    $filter1->isdefault = true;
    $moduleInstance->addFilter($filter1);
    $filter1->addField($field1)->addField($field2, 1)->addField($field3, 2)->addField($mfield1, 3);

    // Sharing Access Setup
    $moduleInstance->setDefaultSharing();

    // Webservice Setup
    $moduleInstance->initWebservice();

    mkdir('modules/'.$MODULENAME);
    echo "OK\n";
}
```

//
language and module file path

vtiger/language/en_us/Expenses.php

vtiger/modules/Expenses/Expenses.php

both file are same.
//

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the file which you have created in root directory(vtiger/Expenses.php) of CRM.

You have to run this file from browser.
http://localhost/vtiger/Expenses.php

There is no issue in your script file you have created.

Answer (score 0):

```
Best method for creating module as below:

For Windows:

- Just open command line
- go in www/html/vtigercrm/vtlib/tools  directory and run php -f console.php command.
- Now Enter your module name and refresh you crm and click on all will display your module

For Linux:
- Just open Terminal
- Go in cd var/www/html/vtigercrm/vtlib/tools  directory

- Run php -f console.php command.
- It will display like

user@user:~$ cd /var/www/html/vtigercrm/vtlib/tools
user@user:/var/www/html/vtigercrm/vtlib/tools$ php -f console.php
Welcome to Vtiger CRM Creator.
This tool will enable you to get started with developing extensions with ease.
Have a good time. Press CTRL+C to "quit".
Choose the options below:
1. Create New Module.
2. Create New Layout.
3. Create New Language Pack.
4. Create Test Language Pack.
5. Import Module.
6. Update Module.
7. Remove Module.
Enter your choice:

- Enter 1
- Enter name of module
- Now refresh crm and click on all menu, you can see your module
```